# Could not determine JSON object type System Argument Exception

Tags: c#, json, mongodb, json.net, mongodb-.net-driver

I'd like to get some help on the below exception that I am facing when trying to set a value to a JSON Object.[image]

`docRoot` is a JSON string that DOES NOT contain an `equipmentId` object, so the goal is to add `equipmentId` to the JSON string and set the value equal to `_eqp["_id"]`. But apparently it seems like the object type is not correct or is not recognized as JSON? Or I have to convert `_eqp["_id"]` to some kind of JSON object? This is where I am confused.

I am getting `_eqp["id"]` from a collection in Mongo DB where it is stored as JSON data, so it is not clear why this value is not being set to `docRoot.equipmentId`.

Below is the JSON from MongoDB

```
{{ "_id" : "81bd9b23-bed7-40f2-83f6-a151c0fd8877", "Name" : "Controller - 391000032", "ParentID" : "e1", "KeyId" : "391000032", "Make" : "", "Model" : "", "ProductType" : "Spotlight_Comp", "Type" : "Controller", "CustomerID" : "b11066e3-d5ab-45e1-a5e8-fe7e0268fc70", "IsActive" : true, "CreatedBy" : "u1", "UpdatedBy" : "u1", "UpdatedOn" : ISODate("2019-09-01T22:22:02.104Z"), "CreatedOn" : ISODate("2018-12-06T17:13:29.358Z"), "ThingNo" : "D-1525887284250-dV2kWoLYDU" }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you call `_equips.Find(...)` and there's a matching document in your database you will get an instance of [BsonDocument](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/reference/bson/bson_document/), special type introduced by MongoDB .NET Driver. This special class introduces it's own .NET type wrappers. Instead of `string` you will get `BsonString`, instead of `int` we have `BsonInt32` and so on. You can obviously convert them to .NET types but when you query your data you're getting your Bson types as the fields of your document.

You didn't mention how `docRoot` gets created but based on your image it looks like you're using [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) library. By saying "docRoot is a JSON string that DOES NOT contain an equipmentId object" you probably mean that `docRoot` is a `dynamic` .NET object created more or less like below:

```
dynamic docRoot = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>("{}");
```

Since you're building `JSON` you should only be able to use types that are convertible to JSON types. More details [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationGuide.htm). Behind the scenes your `docRoot` is of type `DynamicProxyMetaObject` and whenever you try to assign any value it runs [this](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/6b9f467e817854532ea31e6c08abe47c53ac8b5c/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JValue.cs#L602) method.

To fix that you need to convert your value from `BsonString` to regular .NET `string` which can be done using one of two methods shown below:

```
docRoot.equipmentId = _eqp["id"].ToString();
docRoot.equipmentId = _eqp["id"].AsString;
```

Comment: I cant thank you enough for your concise and thorough explanation. This worked perfectly. Thanks for providing the links as well to grow my knowledge no this issue.

Comment: @hfires you're welcome, that was an interesting question !